Error in downloading data directly from internet
I want to download some data in CSV format from internet and used below code
proc import datafile = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sam16tyagi/Machine-Learning-techniques-in-python/master/logistic%20regression%20dataset-Social_Network_Ads.csv' out = Dat dbms = CSV;
run;

However above line generates error like below
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 68         
 69         proc import datafile =
 69       ! 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sam16tyagi/Machine-Learning-techniques-in-python/master/logistic%20regression%20datase
 69       ! t-Social_Network_Ads.csv' out = Dat1 dbms = CSV;
 70         run;
 
 NOTE: Unable to open parameter catalog: SASUSER.PARMS.PARMS.SLIST in update mode. Temporary parameter values will be saved to 
 WORK.PARMS.PARMS.SLIST.
 ERROR: Physical file does not exist, 
 /pbr/biconfig/940/Lev1/SASApp/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sam16tyagi/Machine-Learning-techniques-in-python/master/logistic%20r
 egression%20dataset-Social_Network_Ads.csv. 
 ERROR: Import unsuccessful.  See SAS Log for details.
 NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
 NOTE: PROCEDURE IMPORT used (Total process time):
       real time           0.02 seconds
       user cpu time       0.01 seconds
       system cpu time     0.01 seconds
       memory              8223.21k
       OS Memory           29208.00k
       Timestamp           13/07/2024 10:42:38 AM
       Step Count                        48  Switch Count  5
       Page Faults                       0
       Page Reclaims                     1172
       Page Swaps                        0
       Voluntary Context Switches        27
       Involuntary Context Switches      1
       Block Input Operations            0
       Block Output Operations           40
       
 71         
 72         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 82         



 

Could you please help to understand why it is failing what will be the correct code?

PROC IMPORT is looking for a local file by default, as you can tell from the error (it's searching inside /pbr/biconfig). You can define a URL filename instead:
filename github url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sam16tyagi/Machine-Learning-techniques-in-python/master/logistic%20regression%20dataset-Social_Network_Ads.csv";

proc import datafile=github dbms=csv out=dat;
quit;


Try doing this for your example:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sam16tyagi/Machine-Learning-techniques-in-python/master/logistic%20regression%20dataset-Social_Network_Ads.csv')


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
